# Select Parent having null and not null child

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given 3 tables like:

```
[Table_Main]   ---->   [Table_Sub]   ---->   [Table_Prop]
                1-N                   0-N
```

I want to select item in `[Table_Main]` that :
 - Have multiple `[Table_Sub]`.
 - with `[Table_Sub]` lines that have both `[Table_Prop]` and haven't.

To select those value I use :

```
SELECT      Table_Main.Field_ID
FROM        Table_Main
    INNER JOIN  Table_Sub       on  Table_Main.Field_ID  =  Table_Sub.Table_Main_Field_ID
    LEFT JOIN   Table_Prop      on  Table_Sub.Field_ID   =  Table_Prop.Table_Sub_Field_ID
```

If we rename table Family, Child and Pet. I need family where some childs has pet(s) but some child doesn't.

Family: Id, Name

```
1, Foo      -- Family with 2 childs, one of them has a pet
2, Bar      -- Family with 2 childs, 0 pet
3, Abc      -- Family with 2 childs, both have pet
```

Child: Id, Family_Id, Name

```
1, 1, John      -- Child of Foo
2, 1, Joe       -- Child of Foo
3, 2, Jane
4, 2, Jessica
5, 3, XXX
6, 3, YYY
```

Pet: Id, Child_Id, Name

```
1, 2, FooBar    -- Joe's pet
2, 5, Huey 
3, 6, Dewey
```

Expected Result: 
1, Foo

Family with less than 2 childs is exclude from the exemple has they can satisfy both constraint:
- Has a child with a pet
- Has a child with no pet.

---

Table Creation :

```
CREATE TABLE Family(
    1    INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,Foo  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Family(1,Foo) VALUES (1,'Foo');
INSERT INTO Family(1,Foo) VALUES (2,'Bar');
INSERT INTO Family(1,Foo) VALUES (3,'Abc');


CREATE TABLE Child(
   Id        INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Family_Id INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Name      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Child(Id,Family_Id,Name) VALUES (1,1,'John');
INSERT INTO Child(Id,Family_Id,Name) VALUES (2,1,'Joe');
INSERT INTO Child(Id,Family_Id,Name) VALUES (3,2,'Jane');
INSERT INTO Child(Id,Family_Id,Name) VALUES (4,2,'Jessica');
INSERT INTO Child(Id,Family_Id,Name) VALUES (5,3,'XXX');
INSERT INTO Child(Id,Family_Id,Name) VALUES (6,3,'YYY');


CREATE TABLE Pet(
   Id       INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Family_I INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Name     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Pet(Id,Family_Id,Name) VALUES (1,2,'FooBar');
INSERT INTO Pet(Id,Family_Id,Name) VALUES (2,5,'Huey');
INSERT INTO Pet(Id,Family_Id,Name) VALUES (3,6,'Dewey');
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help others understand your goal here.

Comment: A question would also help.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I though i had simplify the question enough to make it clear, general and data agnostic. But reading 'and' as not exclusive lead people to think I was missing a group by.

Comment: I don't know why are you addressing me. I didn't say the question isn't simple, I've only said that it needs sample data. IMO, if you already bothered to edit your question with sample data, you should have gone the extra mile and provide it as DDL+DML.

Comment: Sorry for the ping, I can only ping one user per comment, I took the last. I will provide an sql fiddle next time. I just don't like  DDL+DML. into simple question because they eat to mutch space for no reason.

Comment: A fiddle is nice and all, but a good question is self contained - for the exact same reasons why link-only answers are low quality: links are not always available. For more infromation: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Done, was delayed by the fact that SqlFiddle is still down. So I build a regex to parse and output the script. I understand the rules, I understand why still find the current version ugly by my standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you desired result.

```
;with family as
(
    select 1 FamilyID, 'Foo' Family union select 2, 'Bar' union select 3, 'ABC'
), child as
(
    select 1 ChildID, 1 FamilyID ,'John' ChildName union
    select 2, 1, 'Joe' union
    select 3, 2, 'Jane' union
    select 4, 2, 'Jessica' union
    select 5, 3, 'XXX'union
    select 6, 3, 'YYY'
), pets as 
(
    select 1 petid , 2 childid, 'FooBar' pet  union
    select 2, 5, 'Huey' union
    select 3, 6, 'Dewey'  
)

SELECT T.FamilyID, Max(Family) Family, MIN(CNT) [Min] , MAX(CNT) [Max]  FROM 
(
    SELECT f.FamilyID, C.ChildID, SUM(case when petid is null then 0 else 1 end) CNT  FROM Family F 
    JOIN Child C ON F.FamilyID = C.FamilyID 
    LEFT JOIN Pets P ON C.ChildID = P.ChildID
    GROUP BY F.FamilyID, C.ChildID 
    ) T JOIN Family F on T.FamilyID = F.FamilyID GROUP BY T.FamilyID 
HAVING MIN(CNT) = 0 AND  MAX(CNT) > 0
```

Comment: Thx, Was about to comment that count return one on null but you edited it. 2 groupy by  is the solution I was trying to get the result from inner querry. Thx a lot for your time.

Comment: if solution worked for you @xdtTransform please accept as answer.

Comment: Always review all my StackOverflow action at the end of the Week. I usually accept answer at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

**Query**

```
 select  family.ID, family.name 
 from      family 
 left join child on family.ID = child.family_id
 left join pet on pet.child_ID = child.Id
 group by  family.name,family.ID
 having  count(child.id) > 1 and  count( pet.id) <>0 and count(child.id) > count( pet.id)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Hi, please expand on your answer as to why this would be a solution to OP's issue. This will help OP and future visitors of the site. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have modified the query as per latest information provided in the question description. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, simple and works. for some reason I was missing `count(child.id) > count( pet.id)`.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are close but if I understand right:

```
With parent as (
select 'Charlie' name from dual union all
select 'Ben' name from dual union all
select 'Bob' name from dual union all
select 'Harry' name from dual 
)
,child as (
select 'Ben' parentname, 'Bebbie' name from dual union all
select 'Ben' parentname, 'Tilda' name from dual union all
select 'Bob' parentname, 'Shara' name from dual union all
select 'Bob' parentname, 'Sandra' name from dual 
)
,pet as (
select 'Tilda' childname, 'Dog' pet from dual union all
select 'Tilda' childname, 'Cat' pet from dual union all
select 'Shara' childname, 'Bird' pet from dual union all
select 'Shara' childname, 'Snake' pet from dual 
)
select pa.name,ch.name,count(pe.pet)
from parent pa
inner join child ch on ch.parentname = pa.name
left join pet pe on pe.childname = ch.name
group by pa.name,ch.name
```